# React-Query in custom hook is being triggered multiple times

Tags: next.js, react-context, react-query

**Sandbox code:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-react-query-9thcky

Hi,
I have wrapping component that uses custom hook with `react-query` to fetch the data and exposes that data, as well as `isLoading` and `isError` state.
Within the wrapping component as long as query is being loaded the whole page should not be rendered. If query fails I want to pass the failover object from the hook.

There's component that's within children of that wrapper that uses the same custom hook, but I would expect it to not need to care about `isLoading` state instead either get data from successful request or failover data if request fails.

I see what's going on, that the custom hook runs the react-query again and it provides undefined data to the component that uses it. Is it expected behaviour? Is it pattern that I can only achive by using context API? (I wanted to switch to `react-query` but it doesn't seem to work as I'd expect it).

Can someone explain me this behaviour like I'm fine, because I'm either to dumb or just sit on it for too long :) Really appreciate any help.

P.S. Yes I know I use index as a key in the sandbox but it's not about it :)

I tried different useQuery options, like turning on refetching at all but it still behaves like the custom hook that's being render later on just doesn't have access to the cache and just starts the whole query over again.

Answer (score 0):

react-query only caches successfully fetched data. Your query goes into `error` state and has no data internally, which means it is considered `stale` and will try to refetch data as soon as a new component mounts.

So when the child mounts, your query will go back to `isLoading` state because it is fetching data and it doesn't have any data internally.

It's hard to say what you are trying to achieve with this, but you can:

- use `placeholderData` to show data while you are loading
- destruct data with a default value to always have data:

```
const { data = FAILOVER_DATA } = useQuery(...)
```

- make sure your query doesn't go into error state by returning `FAILOVER_DATA` from the queryFn if the fetch failed, as it seems to me you want to treat `FAILOVER_DATA` like any data that comes from the api.
- always return data if you don't have data and *not* check the `isError` flag, because the query goes back to loading state:

```
return {
  data: data ?? FAILOVER_DATA,
  isLoading,
  isError
};
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what happened, at the end of the day I ended up using, onError with a function that accesses `queryClient` and invoke its method `setQueyData` with that FAILOVER_DATA. 
That opened my eyes how dummy I was :) Thanks for your answer as well, really appreciate <3